# My Program is not working properly, code is given below

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;    
class TriangleA {    
    public static void main(String s[]){     
        int[][] a=new int[4][4];    
        int sum=0;    
        int max=a[0][0];    
        int min=0;     
        //int min=a[0][0];    
        Random rand = new Random();    
        /*-------------------taking input in array--------------*/    
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){    
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){    
                a[i][j]= rand.nextInt(50);    
            }    
        }    
        /*-----------------------Logic Section--------------------*/    
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){     
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){    
                if(((j==i)||(j>i))&&(a[i][j]>max)){    
                    max=a[i][j];    
                }    
                if(((j==i)||(j>i))&&(a[i][j]<min)&&min!=0){    
                    min=a[i][j];    
                }    
                if(j==i||j>i){    
                    sum = sum +a[i][j];    
                }    
                System.out.println("i"+i+"j"+j+"a[i][j]"+a[i][j] +"max"+max+"min"+min+"ab"+ab);    
                System.out.println();    
            }    
        }    
        System.out.println("=============================================");    
        /*--------------printing array---------------*/    
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){    
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){    
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");    
            }System.out.println();    
        }    
        System.out.println("=================================================="); 
        /*-----------------------------Output-----------------------*/
        System.out.println("Sum is" + sum);
        System.out.println("min is" + min);    
        System.out.println("max is" + max);    
    }    
}
```

In this program max and sum are working fine but when i initialize mi with a[0][0] it takes 0 automatically and if i insert any number for eg. 30 or any number, then it works, can you tell me why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: You say your program is not working correctly, but never mention what "correctly" means.  Also this lack of indenting is making me dizzy

Comment: not working correctly means whenever i'm trying to execute the program, max and sum are working fine but min is always giving 0 as output

Comment: Why you use condition "j==i||j>i"? It means that you loop over half of matrix objects.

Comment: Actually it is what I want, I want to print the min and max and sum of diagnol values or values greater than diagnol

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
&&min!=0
```

from condition. And initialize min as

```
int min=a[0][0];
```

Comment: thanks for reply,
i've already tried by removing 

    &&min!=0 

and by initializing 

    int min=a[0][0];

but its still giving the same output

Answer (score 0):

`int[][] a=new int[4][4];` will create an array and initialize it each element with a default value which 0 in this case. So `int min = a[0][0];` before assigning random values to array  will always initialize min with 0 and your condition `if(((j==i)||(j>i))&&(a[i][j]<min)&&min!=0)` will never allow to change min's value.

So put `min = a[0][0];` after assigning random values to array a.

Hope it would help.

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED**

You are initializing min = a[0][0] BEFORE you assign value to it you need to do it after you have assigned.
Like this :

```
Random rand = new Random();    
        /*-------------------taking input in array--------------*/    
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){    
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){    
                a[i][j]= rand.nextInt(50);    
            }    
        }    
int min = a[0][0];//put it here
```

Comment: min is giving 0 as output even when 0 is not available in array-list.

Comment: As i can see in the code you are debugging the code too. So can you tell at what point does min value is set to 0, give output of debug. And why exactly are you using `(j==i) || (j>i)`

Comment: I want to print min & max from the triangle's  value  which are at diagonal number or greater than diagonal

Comment: And I also checked as after initalizing min as a[0][0] and after setting the values of a[i][j] value of min is still 0 as it is suppose to get the value of a[0][0] just like max